# How to turn on the integrated webcam?

Tags: webcam

How do I turn on the integrated web-cam on Dell Vostro I have Ubuntu 10.10

Answer (score 41):

You need to have an application that works with a web cam. I use [cheese](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/cheese) [image: Install cheese] for that matter.

Install cheese by running the following command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install cheese
```

After installing it, open it and you can now use the web cam.

Answer (score 13):

```
To use the webcam, simply type `cheese` in the terminal.
```

Read below to understand more.

The package `cheese` is required for opening webcam on ubuntu. Please follow the steps below to get it on your ubuntu.

1. Open your **terminal** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>).
2. Type [`cheese`.](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/cheese)
3. ***if*** `cheese` is already ***installed*** then it will prompt `cheese` with webcam on. Now you can use your webcam.
4. ***if***  `cheese` is ***not*** installed, try the steps given below.
5. In the ***terminal*** ,enter `sudo apt-get install cheese`. This will install `cheese`.
6. To use the webcam, simply type `cheese` in the terminal.
7. Direct link for installing cheese http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/cheese

Comment: In 2022 still this solution work for Kubuntu 20.04.✔

Answer (score 7):

This isn't an exact answer but still you can make use of VLC Media Player for this too.

Go to File > Open Capture Device -> Capture Mode select Direct Show

You can take snapshots as well as record videos as well.

Comment: Although not an answer... it is interesting that VLC allows for video capture from camera! `:)`

Answer (score 1):

If Cheese doesnt work for you, try Camorama. Its also found in the Software Center. I think its better than Cheese. I couldn't get Cheese to work on my Acer Aspire One but Camorama worked right out of the box!

Answer (score 0):

Google hangout should also activate the webcam. Invite someone to a video hangout, and it should fire up.

Cheese also worked for me.

Comment: The user is probably asking about a key combination, or an Ubuntu application, therefore in the future, put cheese first.